# gettext does not work

Tags: php, translation

I try to use "gettext" in my app without success.

Here is my file in which I initialize somethings :

```
//methode gettext
switch (Input::get('langue')) {
    case 'fr_FR': $boo_retour_putenv = putenv("LANG=fr_FR");
    break;

    case 'en_GB': $boo_retour_putenv = putenv("LANG=en_GB");
    break;

    case 'de_DE': $boo_retour_putenv = putenv("LANG=de_DE");
    break;
}
// comment s'appelle le fichier contenant les traductions ?
$stg_retour_textdomain = textdomain("messages");

// où se trouve le fichier contenant les traductions ?
$stg_retour_bindtextdomain = bindtextdomain("messages", app_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."lang");

// préciser ici que le fichier des traductions est en codage UTF-8
$stg_retour_bind_textdomain_codeset = bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", "UTF-8");
```

After this script, all seems OK into the vars.

I have this directories for the translations :

[image]

Into these messages files, I can see the right translations. But when I try a :

```
<?php echo gettext('something') ?>
```

it is not translated.

I must not be far away from the solution but I would appreciate any help.

NB :
It used with LARAVEL 4.2
I use poedit to build the messages.mo

Thanks

Dominique

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the locale with `setlocale` after the `textdomain` and `bindtextdomain` calls:

```
$locale = 'fr_FR';
setlocale(LC_ALL, "$locale.utf8");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.utf8"); // for sprintf() etc.
```

It is very important that the selected locale is present on the system, with exactly the same name as the string which you pass to `setlocale`. For the above example this means that the `fr_FR.utf8` locale must exist. You can check which locales are available with

```
locale -a
```

on the command line.

Comment: What do you mean by locale -a ? Is it a dos cmd ?a php cmd ? how to use it ? thanks. Dom

Comment: It's a shell command. On a Unix or Linux machine, you would open a terminal or a SSH connection and enter the command.

Comment: If you're on Windows, `setlocale` and gettext in general are "buggy" anyway … read the warning on php.net/manual/function.setlocale.php Long story short, the locale can switch randomly. So, better use a Linux server (or VM) when you want to use gettext.

Comment: the problem is that I develop on a windows machine , but the production will be on a linux machine. So how to manage that ? Perhaps it means it won't run in development , but sure it will work on a production ?

Comment: I would not rely on that. I'd really recommend to set up a Linux VM that is similar to your production environment (or get some cheap Linux webspace with PHP support). There are many differences between PHP on Windows and PHP on Linux as soon as you're developing more advanced applications.

Comment: I give up ! I tried a lot of things (new release of apache, php, clear cache every where i could, etc...). It seems too complicated for me, i will use the traditional way : an array ! thanks a lot for your help.